# Rendering Problems: Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I have just downloaded Android Studio, and when I try and create an Android Wear project it says:

> Exception raised during rendering: android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.requestApplyInsets()".

I've got no idea what this means or how I go about fixing it. My only guess was maybe SDK? This is what I've got:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.helloworld.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
}
```

*And this is the error:*

[image: error image]

If anyone has any ideas I'd be most grateful!

Thanks

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/watch_view_stub"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:rectLayout="@layout/rect_activity_my"
    app:roundLayout="@layout/round_activity_my"
    tools:context=".MyActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="wear">
</android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub>
```

Comment: please show your xml code

Comment: Just check `android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub` imported properly and build again.

Comment: in .java file, type `WatchViewStub`. if autocomplete works well, in android studio's top menu, click Build->make project